# Как программно скрыть диалог при подключении usb устройства (как в ES Explorer)

Tags: java, android

Увидел такую возможность в es проводнике settings/display/usb plug-in message.

в манифесте через device_filter.xml подписался, нужен код на java или shell script. как они это делают?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

отвечу себе же.
декомпиляция показала, что es проводник использует код библиотеки libamus https://github.com/magnusja/libaums, которая сама в свою очередь использует Storage Access Framework для sdk>=19 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html